# Prediction using fixed effects in glmm

Tags: multiple-regression, mixed-model, interaction, glmm

I have the following generalized linear mixed effects model (mcmcglmm in R) with data based on [this paper](http://www.cell.com/cms/attachment/2042377544/2055424971/mmc2.pdf). `Sex` is a two level factor (M or F), `Group` a two level factor (LL, LO), `Mort` a continuous explanatory variable and `Life` a continuous response.

**What I would like to know is how to estimate the predicted `Life` from the model for the linear relationship with `Mort` for the four combinations of sex and group;**

```
mod2 = MCMCglmm(Life ~ Mort*Sex*Group,
    random = ~ Pop:Year,
    rcov = ~units,  
    family = "gaussian", 
    start = list(QUASI = FALSE), 
    data = DF1) 

summary(mod2)
...
                                  post.mean  l-95% CI  u-95% CI eff.samp  pMCMC    
b1 - (Intercept)                   59.49914  58.09025  60.95132   1000.0 <0.001 ***
b2 - Mort                         -31.71989 -41.68107 -22.98638   1000.0 <0.001 ***
b3 - SexM                          -2.19366  -4.21752  -0.01809   1000.0  0.040 *  
b4 - GroupLO                       -0.31138  -2.95227   2.55287    876.9  0.834    
b5 - Mort:SexM                      5.89476  -7.46922  18.93982   1000.0  0.364    
b6 - Mort:GroupLO                  10.53922  -8.40778  27.26750    913.3  0.220    
b7 - SexM:GroupLO                   2.15210  -1.41979   5.81856   1159.6  0.282    
b8 - Mort:SexM:GroupLO              9.79784 -14.48409  32.54522   1001.8  0.428
```

I'm struggling to find [good literature](http://www.jerrydallal.com/lhsp/reginter.htm) that explains how to estimate the linear relationship when there are multiple categorical interactions occurring.

**What would the respective calculations be? Here are my attempts:**

$ Life_{F,LL} = b_1 + b_2 \times x$

$ Life_{M,LL} = (b_1 + b_3) + (b_2 + b_5) \times x$

$ Life_{F,LO} = (b_1 + b_4) + (b_2 + b_6) \times x$

$ Life_{M,LO} = (b_1 + b_3 + b_4) + (b_2 + b_5 + b_6 + b_7 + b_8) \times x$

**What are the correct formula to get the predicted response for each group?**

---

***Update***; after more thought I think $Life_{M,LO}$ might be this, where all of the terms without `mort` form the intercept and all those with `mort` form the slope:

$ Life_{M,LO} = (b_1 + b_3 + b_4 + b_7) + (b_2 + b_5 + b_6 + b_8) \times x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked the answer out to be the following;

$ Life_{F,LL} = b_1 + b_2 \times x$

$ Life_{M,LL} = (b_1 + b_3) + (b_2 + b_5) \times x$

$ Life_{F,LO} = (b_1 + b_4) + (b_2 + b_6) \times x$

$ Life_{M,LO} = (b_1 + b_3 + b_4 + b_7) + (b_2 + b_5 + b_6 + b_8) \times x$

This is supported using the `predict()` function within R, which gives matching values.