# Paired t-test to test trends in regression coefficients between groups

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, t-test

I have data where I estimate regression coefficients/slopes for two groups (e.g. sex-specific regression coefficients) for a number of single effect regression models. I have used Bayesian methods which allow me to test, individually for each model, whether the regression coefficients of each group are significantly different (and they are generally not significant).

However, there seems to be a trend, that one group has consistently lower coefficients (nearer to zero) than the other.

**Could I then use (/would it be appropriate to use) a paired t-test to see if the (absolute) value of the regression coefficients for one group is consistently lower than the other to test whether one group is more sensitive to explanatory variables?**

E.g. (in R)

```
> a = data.frame("Coefficient" = c(1:10), "GroupA" = abs(rnorm(10,1,1)), "GroupB" = abs(rnorm(10,4,1)))
> a
   Coefficient    GroupA   GroupB
1            1 1.2359143 4.528682
2            2 0.1260180 5.703323
3            3 1.1529601 5.998172
4            4 2.3689296 4.343029
5            5 1.8734228 4.245404
6            6 1.1287780 4.699337
7            7 1.8684325 3.829195
8            8 0.2723389 4.646488
9            9 3.1309934 4.158523
10          10 3.3550409 5.042786
> t.test(a[,2],a[,3],paired=TRUE)

        Paired t-test

data:  a[, 2] and a[, 3]
t = -6.4382, df = 9, p-value = 0.0001198
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -4.146265 -1.990157
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
              -3.068211
```

Comment: Are these coefficients from different models run on the same dataset, different subsets of the same dataset or different datasets entirely ?

Comment: all subsets of the same data (for the response variable and groups), different explanatory variables used in each model. It's data on a trait and regression models test sex-specific responses to various environmental variables. I want to test whether one sex is less sensitive to environment generally (visual suggests that one is consistently less affected than the other, and for some environmental variables this is significant)

Comment: So you are running different models  each on a  different subset of a larger dataset. The models have one predictor in common that you want to compare across the different models ?

Comment: All models have the same response variable, and a common fixed effect of sex (male or female), but vary in the other fixed effect

Comment: IIUC, in the data you have posted, each row refers to a model (run on a different subset of the data), and Group A refers to one sex and Group B to the other sex ?

Comment: yes, the values in the Group A and B columns would be the sex-specific coefficients for each model (the row)

Comment: I'm confused because when you have a sex covariate you only get one estimate for it (assuming there are 2 levels), not two, so I don't know where the 2 columns of values in your table come from ?

Comment: Sex is specified as a fixed effect with two levels, each model allows me to estimate sex-specific regression coefficients, not the covariance between the sexes.

Comment: But you don't get 2 estimates from a factor with 2 levels. A factor with 2 levels as a fixed effect produces just a single estimate.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/214928/prediction-using-fixed-effects-in-glmm

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Sex (main effect) has a single estimate, so could you just explain exactly where the values in the 2 columns come from ?

Comment: the regression coefficient for one sex (using the group LL in the linked question) would be `b2` and `b2+b5` in the other sex

Comment: If one column is `b2` and the other column is `b2+b5` then you are really interested in knowing whether `b5` (which is the interaction between `Mort` and `sex`) is different from zero. Also, it is not *"using the group `LL` in the linked question"* since `Group` is not involved in either `b2` or `b5`. I think you need to re-write the the question to provide a lot more detail about what you actually want to test.

Comment: That is how it works in the MCMCglmm package, I've discussed this with the author. For example, in the linked question the output "intercept" is the intercept for the first level of the factor (female), and SexM is the sex-specific intercept for males, relative to the female intercept.

Comment: Yes, that's completely normal. So the "effect" of sex is just the estimate labelled "SexM". However you just told me that you want to compare `b2`, which is the fixed effect of `Mort`, with `b2+b5` which is the fixed effect of `Mort` plus the *interaction* between `Mort` and `Sex`. Or did you mean `b1` and `b1+b3` ?

Comment: I have done comparison of the sex-specific regression coefficients for each model (as stated in the question) - I am trying to find a valid way to test for a *trend across models*, e.g. are male specific slopes closer to zero?

Comment: Please understand that in order to give advice it's important to understand the problem. I still don't understand where `b2` and `b2+b5` come into it.

Comment: ´b2´ is the female specific slope, ´b2 + b5´ is the male specific slope - I don't know what you do not understand about this question. I have told you I have tested for differences between these slopes for each model, but that I would like to test if there is a general trend. **I am not asking how to test for an effect of sex within models, I am asking how to test for consistency of the sex effect across models.**

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a paired t-test would be appropriate, since it takes no account of the uncertainty in the individual estimates.

I would suggest:

1. Run the models on the full dataset in order to achieve greater power.
2. Conduct a meta-analysis of the results you have on the subsets.